# Integrating Bootstrap CSS framework on a single page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Our agency has been contracted to develop a few pages within an existing CMS. I would like to use the Twitter Bootstrap framework to scaffold these pages. However, I am worried about conflicts with the existing CSS on the site for the templated areas that we are not modifying.

Rather than bring in Bootstrap styles for the entire document on those pages and manually troubleshoot all style conflicts, I am wondering if it is a better solution to compile Boostrap CSS with a selector prefix (`#body-content` for example) to isolate those styles to the region of the document we are modifying.

Are there any risks to this approach? Any reason why this approach might not work or should be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your questions

> Are there any risks to this approach?Any reason why this approach might not work or should be avoided?

See, the only issue you will have is when you get an update to the bootstrap framework, because you use your own custom compiled css, you will have to recompile it for the new version.
If you stick to the original css, you simply replace the current css with the new version.
and everything falls into place.
About conflicts, i would suggest that you make changes to a custom css file that overides the boostrap.css, so that you get the chance to check what is actually conflicting.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="boostrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
```